# Emacs: How to change "M-x" prompt to something else?

Tags: emacs

I have `execute-extended-command` bound to alt+a. So when in minibuffer, when i press it, the read-only prompt saying "M-x" is irrelevant for me. I want to change it to something else like "execute command:". How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This prompt is hard-coded. You would need to either redefine `read-extended-command`, or advise `completing-read` (but that seems a fairly tenuous approach).

See <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `read-extended-command` <kbd>RET</kbd>

There are comments in the code referring to this very issue:

```
;; This isn't strictly correct if `execute-extended-command'
;; is bound to anything else (e.g. [menu]).
;; It could use (key-description (this-single-command-keys)),
;; but actually a prompt other than "M-x" would be confusing,
;; because "M-x" is a well-known prompt to read a command
;; and it serves as a shorthand for "Extended command: ".
```

Honestly, given the lack of a clean solution, I wouldn't bother trying to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [smex](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex), which is an improvement upon the built-in `execute-extended-command`; it allows you to customize the prompt via the variable `smex-prompt-string`.

Or, if you've got the Emacs source installed, you can jump straight to the implementation: just <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `execute-extended-command` <kbd>RET</kbd>